# STM32 Uart Interrupt Burst transmit problem

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, uart, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to implement uart in interrupt mode, but something go wrong obviously. Here is my problem: I want to send some strings as soon as possible (example: want to send 10 times string "test123") but for some reason that isn't possible (I make some mistake but can't understand where is that mistake). I use STM32CubeIDE, mcu is stm32f407vgt6. After first successful transmit code fall into Error_Handler() which is not acceptable. When I use delays between each transmit all string will be successful transmitted but why that can be done in this way.Here is code

```
uint8_t TxData[] = "test123\n";
bool flagTxCmpltUsart = true;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){`

    if(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart3, TxData, strlen(TxData)) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    } 
        Wait_Unit_Uart_Tx_Is_Complete();
        Reset_Uart_Tx_Complete_Flag();}
void Reset_Uart_Tx_Complete_Flag(void) 
{
    flagTxCmpltUsart = false;
}

void Wait_Unit_Uart_Tx_Is_Complete(void)
{
    while(!flagTxCmpltUsart){}
}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(huart->Instance == USART3)
    {
        flagTxCmpltUsart = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(!flagTxCmpltUsart){}` the initial value of `flagTxCmpltUsart ` is true... change `bool flagTxCmpltUsart = true;
` to `bool flagTxCmpltUsart = false;
`

Comment: Thanks for help but that is not solution.. In first sequence `bool flagTxCmpltUsart` can be either false either true.

Comment: Alex I do that too, but same again, code will be fall into Error_Handler()

Comment: You should clear the interrupt flag. Also have you checked the return value of _HAL_UART_Transmit_IT_ ?

Comment: I do that too.. I check that, I got HAL_ERROR                                                                                                             `void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART3_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart3);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_IRQn 1 */
  flagTxCmpltUsart3 = true;
  /* USER CODE END USART3_IRQn 1 */
} `

Comment: `In first sequence bool flagTxCmpltUsart can be either false either true.` I don't understand that. No. Before `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` then `flagTxCmpltUsart` has to be set to false. Ie. `Reset_Uart_Tx_Complete_Flag` should be called before `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT`, not after it.

Comment: Volatile missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)` is called in the interrupt context, you should set your complete flag as

`volatile bool flagTxCmpltUsart = true;`

To make sure the compiler knows that is could change outside of the normal program flow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your UART status, you'll get error if the transmission line is busy. Try to insert the following code between each call;

```
while (HAL_UART_GetState(&UartHandle) != HAL_UART_STATE_READY){
   //Do Something..
}
```